# YouTube referer/tracking URLs

Tags: youtube, url

YouTube has some kind of tracking system which adds `feature` to the link depending upon the source. For example, in the following example, from the `feature` I know that it is from the sidebar (related questions)

www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX&**feature=related**

My question is when the url with `feature=g-like` is generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&feature=g-like` is generated when you visit your own liked video feed.

Visit [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/), sign in and then go to the home page clicking the logo of YouTube where it shows you your social feed. There, click the like button beside your profile picture, as highlighted below:

[image]

Hover over or copy the URL of any of those videos YouTube says you liked and you'll see `&feature=g-like` appended to them.

Comment: That’s not what the OP asked (he already stated what you are saying in your answer). He’s asking what does `g-like` in particular mean.

Comment: @Alex `My question is when the url with feature=g-like is generated?` ... ?

Comment: Oh. He is asking about the `g-like` in particular. Sorry misunderstood. Will update. :)

Comment: @Alex fixed the answer.